# how to get past this error message when i load the site

Tags: php, html, symfony

im installing my website but i keep getting this error i really dont know where to start

> Compile Error: Declaration of
>   AppBundle\Repository\PackRepository::find($pack) must be compatible
>   with Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::find($id, $lockMode = NULL,
>   $lockVersion = NULL)

ive tried changing the values to null but still the same thing

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

/**
 * PackRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class PackRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository {

    /*public function findAll() {
        return $this->findBy(
            array(),
            array('amount' => 'ASC')
        );
    }*/
    public function getPacksCount() {

        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT COUNT(u) FROM AppBundle:Pack u")
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
    }
    public function find($pack) {

        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT f FROM AppBundle:Pack f WHERE f.id = ?1")
            ->setParameter(1, $pack)
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }

    public function findAll() {

        return $this->getEntitymanager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Pack p ORDER BY p.amount ASC")
            //->createQuery("SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Pack p WHERE p.amount != 5000 ORDER BY p.amount ASC")
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

its expected to load staright to the website but this keeps occuring

Comment: Try to remove function `find` Repository->find() should do what you want thanks to doctrine

Comment: I strongly advise against implementing methods on the repository, that already exist... like find, findAll, findBy[Property] etc.

Comment: Not so much removing your find but renaming it to something like findPack.  Your definition of find conflicts with the existing definition.  Hence the error.  Your IDE should flag these sorts of things.

Comment: read up on inheritance in php and overriding functions in sub-classes. this error happens, when you override a function and change the signature of that function